# eslint-plugin-security throws type error while linting Mongoose exec() method

Tags: node.js, mongoose, eslint

I'm using `Nodejs`, `Eslint ^7` and `Mongoose ^5`. I have added `eslint-plugin-security ^1` recommended rules to my **.eslintrc.js** as below :

```js
parserOptions: {
  ecmaVersion: 2021,
},

env: {
  commonjs: true,
  es6: true,
  browser: false,
  node: true,
},

plugins: ['security'],

extends: [
  'plugin:security/recommended',
],
```

When I run eslint, I get the below TypeError :

```sh
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.30.0

TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
Occurred while linting /app/api/src/Repository/AppLog.js:38
    at MemberExpression (/app/api/node_modules/eslint-plugin-security/rules/detect-child-process.js:34:87)
    at /app/api/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/safe-emitter.js:45:58
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.emit (/app/api/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/safe-emitter.js:45:38)
    at NodeEventGenerator.applySelector (/app/api/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/node-event-generator.js:293:26)
    at NodeEventGenerator.applySelectors (/app/api/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/node-event-generator.js:322:22)
    at NodeEventGenerator.enterNode (/app/api/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/node-event-generator.js:336:14)
    at CodePathAnalyzer.enterNode (/app/api/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/code-path-analysis/code-path-analyzer.js:711:23)
    at /app/api/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/linter.js:960:32
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I checked the line that the error points to, But I didn't find any problem with that.

Here is my code on `/app/api/src/Repository/AppLog.js:38` :

```js
async list() {
  return this.LogModel.find().exec();
}
```

everything works fine when I remove the **eslint-plugin-security** plugin. I guess there is a problem with the library itself.

Any idea for solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is my problem too. I have also created an [issue](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security/issues/69) for that on [its](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security) repository,

The error occurs when eslint faces any [Query.prototype.exec()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) in the code that is namesake with `child_process.exec()` method of Node.js.

There is a possible solution to this problem which I have described [here](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security/issues/69), But it's still open and I have no other idea how to fix it another and/or better way.

Comment: Thank you. I would appreciate any other or better solutions.